# Build macro Variables on another macro var

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I would like to "shortcut" this function of a macro variable

```
intnx('YEAR',"&starting_year"D,-5,'S');
```

with another macro variable. Is it possible ?

something like:

```
%let start = intnx('YEAR',"&starting_year"D,-5,'S');
```

Of course this code-line doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide example values of STARTING_YEAR and the corresponding values of START that should result?  Do you want the year or the first day of the year? Do you want it formatted as DATE9 string?

Comment: STARTING_YEAR is a prompt like '20MAR1999' , START would be '20MAR1994' and yes date9 format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `%SYSFUNC()` to call functions in macro code. You can use the optional format specification to control how the results is converted to the text that is stored in the macro variable.

So if you start with macro variable in `DATE.` format you could generate the date that was 5 years before that date like this:

```
%let start=%sysfunc(intnx(year,"&starting_date"d,-5,s),date9);
```

This would convert `20MAR1999` to `20MAR1994`.  Or it would convert `29FEB04` to `28FEB1999`.

Answer (score 1):

%sysfunc lets you call regular SAS functions in the macro language. Perhaps something like (untested) :

```
%let start = %sysfunc(intnx(YEAR,"&starting_year"D,-5,S));
```